# Saving rails request to JSON/YML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm using service which sends Webhooks to my application. I want to write RSpec test for handling them. It's important to have this request exactly the same (remote caller IP, headers with encrypted content).

I tried to save request as json:

```
class WebhookController < ApplicationController
  def some_callback
    File.open('temp/request_example.json','w') do |f|
     f.write request.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

so I could later do:

```
describe WebhookController do
   subject { get :some_callback, JSON.parse(File.open('temp/request_example.json')) }
   it 'does something' do;end
end
```

but unfortunately you cannot call `request.to_json`(`request.to_json
IOError: not opened for reading`). You can't either get directly to `request.body` or `request.headers`.

How to save such request for later usage in tests? Is there any gem for it?

Comment: `request.body.read` should work :/